# Code to flag a square number is not working, why is this?

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

I am trying to learn Java and have to create a small script that tells you if a number you have selected is a square number or not:

```
public class NumberShapes{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class Number {
            int number;

            public boolean isSquare(){
                int y = 1;
                int squareNumber = 1;

                while (squareNumber <= number) {
                    y += 1;
                    squareNumber = (y * y);
                }

                if (squareNumber == number) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
        Number myNumber = new Number();

        myNumber.number = 9;

        System.out.println("Is " + myNumber.number + " a square number?: " + myNumber.isSquare());

}
}
```

Let's say you choose a number, in this case `myNumber = 9`. The logic is then supposed to take every integer `< 9` and square it. If any number is squared to equal `myNumber`, then `myNumber` is a square number (and returns `true`) otherwise it isn't and returns `false`.

However when I try with `9`, I get the output to be `false`, when it should be `true`.

My thinking is that somehow it squares numbers up to `9`, but then instead of comparing `9` with `9`, it is comparing `3` with `9`, and as `3 != 9`, it outputs as `false`. Is this correct?

How would I fix it?

(Just FYI, I have seen an alternative where you can square root the number and check if it is an integer, but I would like to figure out why this way isn't working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your loop's condition:

```
while (squareNumber <= number) {
    y += 1;
    squareNumber = (y * y);
}
```

When `y` reaches `3`, and `squareNumber` becomes `9` (3 * 3), you are not exiting the loop, since `9 <= 9` is true. Therefore, in the next iteration of the loop, you assign 4 * 4 to `squareNumber` before ending the loop, and you return `false`.

Change the condition to `while (squareNumber < number)`.